# alert(message) returns an empty string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, authentication

SOLVED by @Hanky 웃 Panky!

I am implementing a login function.

The javascript part:

```
function login() {
    var n = $('#userl').val();
    var p = $('#passl').val();
    if ( n != "" && p != ""){
        $.post("functions.php",{userl: n, passl: p}).done(function(mesaj){
            if(mesaj  == "")
               alert("!!!!!!!!!!EMPTY STRING!!!!!");
            else
            alert(mesaj);
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("Enter name and/or passwort");
    }
};
```

And the function from function.php looks:

```
function login($nume,$parola)
{
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM `Users` WHERE nume ='".$nume."' ANY password = '".md5($parola)."'";
    $q = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$q)
        die(json_encode(array("mesaj" => "Invalid")));
    else{
        $x = mysql_fetch_array($q);
        if (empty($x))
            die(json_encode(array('mesaj' => 'The user does not exist')));
        else {
        //    $user = new User($x['id']);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $x['id'];
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "yes";
            die(json_encode(array("mesaj"=>"you were logged")));
        }

        }
    //this part may be useless
    die(json_encode(array("mesaj"=>"you were not logged")));
}


if (isset($_POST['nume']) AND isset($_POST['parola']))
         login($_POST['nume'], $_POST['parola']);
```

The problem is it keeps alerting the EMPTY STRING and I think it doesn'n even acccess my login function from php...so the message comes back the way it went: empty

Comment: Why would you use the a non-empty string `"EMPTY STRING!!!!!!!"`? That's just silliness. If you want people to help you don't do silly things like that. If it's an empty string, use something like `""`. If it's not an empty string, don't call it `"EMPTY STRING!!!!!!!"`.

Comment: a row was deleted by mistake when I`ve written the quest :D sorry. I have edited it

Comment: @Mike i wish i could put that comment of yours on top of every stack overflow page and up-vote it 100x to stress how important that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  $.post("functions.php",{userl: n, passl: p})
```

Compare that with

```
if (isset($_POST['nume']) AND isset($_POST['parola']))
```

And spot your error :)

*You are sending `user1` and `pass1` and in PHP you are checking for `nume` and `parola` which don't exist obviously.*

Comment: That could also be a translation error when pasting into StackOverflow since it's an English-only site.